# Re-signing a Click Once Application

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, mage

I am trying to re-sign a click once application after updating the config following the instruction [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/04/29/signing-and-re-signing-manifests-in-clickonce.aspx) by running this

> mage.exe –Update MyApp.Client.application –appmanifest    "Application
>   Files\MyApp_3_6_7_93\MyApp.exe.manifest"

But I keep getting the error :

> Unrecognized command line argument '-appmanifest'  Unrecognized
>   command line argument 'Application
>   Files\MyApp.Client._3_6_7_93\MyApp.exe.manifest'

Comment: You seem to have a weird "long dash". Make sure to type the dash yourself.

Comment: Yea that resolved the initial error, i am now getting Internal error, please try again. Prefix 'co.v1' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Its case sensitive

You could use -appm

```
Commands
        -New <file_type>                  -n
        -Update <file_name>               -u
        -Sign <file_name>                 -s
        -ClearApplicationCache            -cc
        -Help [verbose]                   -h -?



Options
        -AppCodeBase <path>               -appc
        -AppManifest <path>               -appm
        -CertFile <file_name>             -cf
        -CertHash <hash>                  -ch
        -FromDirectory <path>             -fd
        -IconFile <file_path>             -if
        -IncludeProviderURL <true|false>  -ip
        -Install <true|false>             -i
        -Name <name>                      -n
        -Password <password>              -pwd
        -Processor <processor>            -p
        -ProviderURL <url>                -pu
        -Publisher <publisher_name>       -pub
        -MinVersion <version #|none>      -mv
        -SupportURL <support_url>         -s
        -TimeStampUri <uri>               -ti
        -ToFile <file_name>               -t
        -TrustLevel <level>               -tr
        -UseManifestForTrust <true|false> -um
        -Version <version>                -v
        -WPFBrowserApp <true|false>       -wpf

Use "mage -help verbose" for more detailed help
```

Comment: I have used -appm still same error, and I have used -AppManifest too still same exact error

Comment: it is after a path not a file - perhaps this is what upsets it - if it is, its a poor error